# Is there a github or source code for the contacts portion of the Phone app in Android?

Tags: java, android, git, contacts

I'm trying to develop an Android app - and it requires the ability to add contacts. The method of adding contacts and searching for them in the Phone app of Android looks super good and works really well. Does anyone know if there is an existing Git repository for this or how I could port the source code over to have the same functionality? To clarify, the app I am building does not need any calling functionality. I am just looking for a place to store contacts with name, address, and some other information. I found [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/eclair-sholes-release/src/com/android/phone) but I don't know which classes I need. Any information is much appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The Phone app I am referring to looks like [this](https://puu.sh/sg69K/38b84188b2.png).
It's a screencapture of a YouTube Video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method of adding contacts and searching for them in the Phone app of Android looks super good and works really well.

There are hundreds of pre-installed phone and contacts apps, spread across thousands of device models, spread across ~2 billion devices. Many, if not most, of these apps have a distinct look.

> Does anyone know if there is an existing Git repository for this or how I could port the source code over to have the same functionality?

Probably not, as whatever you are looking at probably is a proprietary app, developed by the device manufacturer.

> I am just looking for a place to store contacts with name, address, and some other information

[That would be `ContactsContract`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html), which is part of the Android SDK.

You are certainly welcome to look at [the AOSP Contacts app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Contacts/) for inspiration, though you may not find its code to be especially readable. Also, most likely that project cannot be built in isolation in Android Studio, as most of the AOSP apps are designed to be built as part of a full firmware build.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

It looks like this by the way: https://puu.sh/sg69K/38b84188b2.png

It's a screencapture of a YouTube Video

Comment: Do you know where I could find that?

Comment: @user3003214: Since that screenshot shows an API Level 23 emulator, *probably* what you are seeing is the Android 6.0 edition of the AOSP Contacts app that I linked to in the answer.

Comment: Do you know how I can import this into Android Studio? I'm running into a lot of trouble

Comment: @user3003214: As I noted in my answer, you cannot build this project from Android Studio.